# Generate a installer for macos using moditect and ant

Tags: java, macos, javafx, moditect

Yesterday I fixed generating runtime-image, but now when I want to generate an installer for Mac I am generate a pkg, dmg file, but the app is damaged

[image]

For Windows this settings works.

```
        <profile>
            <id>jpackage</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>jpackage</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target>
                                        <property name="version" value="1.0"/>
                                        <ant antfile="${basedir}/build.xml">
                                            <target name="current"/>
                                        </ant>
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

For Windows

```
    <target name="jpackage-win64">
        <echo message="Run jpackage from ${platform}"/>
        <exec command="${JAVA_HOME}\bin\jpackage">
            <arg line="--type exe"/>
            <arg line="--dest installer"/>
            <arg line="--name 'DocStore Sync'"/>
            <arg line="--vendor 'Esempla Systems S.R.L'"/>
            <arg line="--copyright 'Copyright © 2023 Esempla Systems. All rights reserved.'"/>
            <arg line="--description 'DocStore Sync application'"/>
            <arg line="--license-file src\main\resources\license.txt"/>
            <arg line="--app-version ${version}"/>
            <arg line="--verbose"/>
            <arg line="--win-menu"/>
            <arg line="--win-menu-group 'DocStore Sync'"/>
            <arg line="--win-dir-chooser"/>
            <arg line="--win-shortcut"/>
            <arg line="--icon src\main\resources\icon.ico"/>
            <arg line="--module docstore.sync/com.esempla.docstore.Launcher"/>
            <arg line="--runtime-image target\runtime-image"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
```

For mac

```
    <target name="mac">
        <echo message="Run jpackage from ${platform}"/>
        <exec command="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jpackage">
            <arg line="--type pkg"/> <!-- Use the pkg type for macOS -->
            <arg line="--dest installer"/>
            <arg line="--name 'DocStoreSync'"/>
            <arg line="--vendor 'Esempla Systems S.R.L'"/>
            <arg line="--copyright 'Copyright © 2023 Esempla Systems. All rights reserved.'"/>
            <arg line="--description 'DocStore Sync application'"/>
            <arg line="--app-version ${version}"/>
            <arg line="--verbose"/>
            <arg line="--mac-package-identifier com.esempla.docstore"/>
            <arg line="--module docstore.sync/com.esempla.docstore.Launcher"/>
            <arg line="--main-class docstore.sync/com.esempla.docstore.Launcher"/>
<!--            <arg line="&#45;&#45;main-jar docstore-sync-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>-->
            <arg line="--icon src/main/resources/icon.icns"/>
            <arg line="--runtime-image target/runtime-image"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
```

Runtime image generated with moditect

[image]

I want to generate an installer, but it is broken.

Comment: You need to [sign the app package on OS X](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/jpackage/support-application-features.html#GUID-8D9F0607-91F4-4070-8823-02FCAB12238D).  To do that I think you need to buy and use the correct certificate that Apple has issued to you as part of your Apple Developer program membership.